# Java Cannot find symbols

Tags: java

I have a class file Packet.class in NetBeans, however when I try to use it, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\goh\Desktop\Workspace\NetSim_Alvin_Oo_U1022711A\src\PFrame.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
   public Packet info = new Packet();
  symbol:   class Packet
  location: class PFrame
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have a class named Packet somewhere? Java is saying that it can't find it. Did you forget to import it?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your problem including about where Packet is located, how you're trying to use it or import it? These details may be very important.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `Packet.class` file to your build path. I believe this can be done in netbeans by right-clicking your project and selecting 'Properties'. Note that it is better, if possible, to add a jar file instead of a class file. If you have the `Packet.java` file you could simply add that to the source folder.

Comment: problem.if NetSim n is not a main class and netbeans cannot detect it what should I do?